# Dead link on the "What is reputation?" page in the Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, broken-link

The Help Center page, [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), contains the following paragraph:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination
>   of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But Bounty awards, accepted
>   answers, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily
>   reputation limit.

Here, *association bonuses* links to https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/, which does no longer exist. According to web archive, the page seems to have moved to a [now equally lifeless new address](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/) and then deleted. A possible replacement could be [this slightly newer blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/19/new-automatic-account-association/) (which by the way also links to the dead page).

Comment: An even better link would be [the canonical Q&A on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 5):

As recommended by Cody Gray in the comments on the question, I've updated this link to go to the [MSE FAQ on the Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work). This was a network-wide issue and was also reported on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349655/what-is-reputations-association-bonuses-link-is-404/349656#349656).

Thanks for bringing this to our attention so that we could fix it.